# creating custom - regular expression searchable - variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

**The scenario:** I'm creating is a mini-editor and would like to have the option of highlighting text in it, and creating a custom variable out of the highlighted text.

So, selecting the text opens a new textbox below the text area - to the left of the new `textbox` is the text selected (this would be the key - e.g. `"selected_text"`), and in the right - in the `textbox` - will be the value. this key/value pair will all be stored as part of a js object, and brought up later - as part of the full text that's currently in the textarea - in a wizard style environment.

So, the first part I can do - grab the text, put it in a new div with a `textbox`, and save it in the `js` object. It's the regular expression search that comes in the wizard that I'm not sure of.

I was thinking of wrapping the key with carets -  something like ^^selected_text^^ - and then do a regex search for that. once I have the key, I can look it up in my object, and replace the text. i'm not sure how to do this with regular expressions...

Something like this:

```
this will be a ^^custom_variable^^ and so will ^^chocolate_cake^^
```

So, first question: is something like this possible?
Second question - is anyone aware of a plugin that's already written?

### EDIT

I'm trying to search for this using:

```
var hover_match = new Array();
hover_match = card_text.match(/\x01([^\x01]*)\x01//g);
```

card_text equals (for example) `x01Replacex01 Me! x01dfdx01` which should return two results, and store them into hover_match. but.. hover_match is coming back null, which is what match brings back if it can't find anything...

did I misunderstand the comment and how to use x01?

Comment: If you are going to embed the variable within the text, I would wrap it with something like 1 (decimal) control code. Then to search for it with a regex:  `/\x01([^\x01]*)\x01/` where the variable name will be capture in group 1.

Comment: curious: why is x01 better than ^^? is it because ^ is a regular expression character?

Comment: No, ^ is a printable character that may be part of the text outside of `^^custom_variable^^`

Comment: I'm sorry, but that regex isn't working for me. i added what i now have into the question...